# How to single out country data from a world data map?

Tags: python, grass-gis, r, intersection, area

Say that i have two "data sources";

1. A global map of average wind speeds,
2. A shape file (or similar information) of all country borders in the world.

How do i combine these two sources and extract the average wind speeds of a country?

The wind speed data is structured such that each lat-lon combination has an average wind speed:

```
Lat, Lon, AvgSpeed
-90, -180, 4.54
-90, -179, 4.55
-90, -178, 4.57
...
```

The output should be somewhat similar to the input, but with "an extra column" for country:

```
Lat, Lon, AvgSpeed, Country
-90, -180, 4.54, Country 1
-90, -179, 4.55, Country 1
-90, -178, 4.57, Country 2
...
```

I have Grass GIS, R and Python installed - but your answer need not be restricted to these software packages/programming languages.

Comment: Can we use postgis in the answer?

Answer (score 4):

You first need to import the CSV file with [v.in.ascii](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.in.ascii.html) to create a vector points map. Add a new column "Country" of varchar(25) with [v.db.addcol](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.db.addcol.html). Then simply populate the new column with [v.what.vect](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.what.vect.html) (see also example in that manual page).

Comment: This is great - but not exactly what i was looking for. This gives me and min, max, average, etc of each country. But what i would like is all the AvgSpeed of each lat-lon inside a country. The output should be similar to the input but with an extra column with countries (i updated the question)

Comment: Ah, I read to fast, I have rewritten my answer and moved the previous example into the GRASS Wiki at http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Zonal_statistics

Answer (score 4):

In R, the gIntersection() tool from the rgeos package should intersect and match the data, but doesn't seem to be working (gives only the shapes, not the dataframes (see @ari-b-friedman's [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35060/rgeos-drops-associated-values-when-intersecting-polygons)).

QGIS **will** work for you if you use the Vector|Geoprocessing|Intersect tool, giving you a set of all the points with the overlapping country data merged; this is odd as both R and QGIS should be using the same method.

Using R, you can extract a single country's data with `overlay()`:

```
# Load the maptools and a shapefile of all countries
library(maptools)
world <- readShapePoly("~/workspace/World_countries.shp")

# Select a single country from the names:
kenya <- world[world$CNTRY_NAME == "Kenya",]
plot(kenya)
```

[image: Kenya outline]

```
# Create a wind dataset and make it SpatialPoints
wind <- data.frame(lon = rep(30:45, 11), lat = rep(-5:5, each = 16), 
        AvgSpeed = rnorm(11*16, mean = 5, sd = 2))
coordinates(wind) <- ~lon+lat
plot(wind, add = T, pch = 20, cex = 0.4, col = 'red')
```

[image]

```
# Extract the vector of overlapping points
kenya.wind.over <- overlay(wind, kenya)

# Extract just those points from the wind data
kenya.wind <- wind[!is.na(kenya.wind.over),]

# And plot to see if it looks correct
plot(kenya)
plot(wind, col = 'gray', add = T, cex = 0.2)
plot(kenya.wind, col = 'red', cex = kenya.wind$AvgSpeed/10, add = T, pch = 20)
```

[image]

You could loop over the countries data frame (`for country in CNTRY_NAME`) and cbind the resulting rows, but seems much easier just to do it in QGIS.