# How to do union that results to a SpatialPolygonDataFrame in R?

Tags: shapefile, r, union

I have the following code

```
coastline<-readOGR(dsn=".",layer="shp")
wetlands<-readOGR(dsn=".",layer="shp")
wetb<-gBuffer(wetlands,width=500,byid=T)
wetb2<-gBuffer(wetlands,width=1000,byid=T)
u<-gUnion(wetb2,wetb)
plot(u)
```

EDIT

```
u<-raster::union(wetb2,wetb)
u2<-raster::union(coastline, u)
  plot(u2)
```

gives

```
Error in if (is.numeric(i) && i < 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
  Self-intersection at or near point 699045.17841763003 4339815.8708455302
```

gUnion results to a SpatialPolygon but i need SpatialPolygonDataFrame. How can i do union that has that outcome?

Answer (score 1):

All the g.. functions seem to discard the data by design, and you have to fiddle them back into a spatial dataframe (Don't ask me how...)

Try using the `union` from the `raster package`. Haven't tried union, but intersect etc. worked as expected, producing spatial dataframes.

Comment: Functions from the raster package cannot be applied to vectors.

Comment: Have you even tried ??? See my older answer on an intersect problem: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35060/rgeos-drops-associated-values-when-intersecting-polygons/128088#128088

Comment: Can you tell me how to use the union from the raster package since if i write union it will use the base function.

Comment: you can use (generically) `package::function` to access a particular function in a package

Comment: Have you loaded the raster library? If yes, try raster::union See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564564/r-2-functions-with-the-same-name-in-2-different-packages

Comment: it says Error in if (is.numeric(i) && i < 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning message:
In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
  Self-intersection at or near point 699045.17841763003 4339815.8708455302

Comment: Hard to tell from the distance, but for me that sounds like that you have topological errors in one or both layers. Did you produce them within R or are they just imported? If imported, check for errors in GIS. Or try using a tiny buffer (1cm or so) before union, maybe this will resolve the problem.

Comment: Actually i used it two times. The first worked well but the second returned this error.i will edit my question so you can understand.

Comment: h, just have to read your question. Imported, and already applies a buffer ... mhmm. No idea. Am not the "real" R guru ;)