# How do I retain all attribute data when clipping two polygons in R?

Tags: polygon, r, clip, fields-attributes

I would first like to say that my question is very much similar to [this answered one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64537/clip-polygon-and-retain-data), but the proposed solutions don't seem to be working for me. I think that my question is slightly different, as I'm performing a clip/intersection rather than a difference. Onto it!

My input can be found [here at the FEWSNET website](http://www.fews.net/east-africa), and an example country outline can be downloaded [here at the GADM site](http://gadm.org/download). I've been using the Ethiopia ESRI shapefile.

What I'm trying to do is quite simple. I first clip the country shapefile to the FEWSNET shapefile. Once the clip is performed, I need to symbolize the ML1 variables from the latter shapefile. In QGIS, I perform the vector clip, then with the newly clipped shapefile, I go to Properties > Style, change it from single to categorized, then choose my symbology for the ML1 category.

The code that I have so far has also been quite simple:

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

#read in ML and Ethiopia shapefiles
ea.ml1 <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/Mapping-R/Ethiopia", layer = "EA201507_ML1")
eth <- readOGR(dsn = "D:/Mapping-R/Ethiopia", layer = "ETH_adm0")

#perform clip
eth.clip <- gIntersection(ea.ml1, eth, byid = TRUE)
```

The problem is that the data that I need to symbolize (ML1) exists under `ea.ml1@data$ML1`. When I perform the clip, it appears that `ea.ml1@data` is lost altogether. How do I retain that data with my clip so that I can properly symbolize it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `intersect`:

```
library(raster)
eth.clip <- intersect(ea.ml1, eth)
```

Comment: Great, easy enough! What is the functional difference between `rgeos::gIntersection` and `raster::intersect` that makes this work?

Comment: `raster::intersect` uses `rgeos::gIntersection` but it also takes care of the attributes, which if you use rgeos which only works on the geometries. The raster package has a set of related functions. See ?'raster-package'
section XIV